# command-line grep for a string with '$' in it?

Tags: command-line, grep, freebsd

I'm trying to find where two variables are being concatenated in a directory of scripts, but when I try the following:

```
grep -lire "$DATA_PATH . $AWARDS_YEAR" *
```

I get "undefined variable" errors...

I thought I could escape the $s by using:

```
grep -lire "\$DATA_PATH . \$AWARDS_YEAR" *
```

But I get the same error - so, how do you grep for strings with $s in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tcsh is a little different about variables than the usual shells, and it's the default on FreeBSD.

So, just use single quotes, `'$VAR'`, or escape the `$` outside of the quotes: `\$"VAR"`

Comment: Using single quotes is the most nearly portable solution-it works across most shells on Unix-like systems.  (Windows is a separate discussion.)

Answer (score 2):

Put it in single quotes, with the escaping slash:

```
grep -lire '\$DATA_PATH . \$AWARDS_YEAR' *
```

Also note, that the dot (.) is a regex character. If you don't want it to be, escape it, too (or don't use the -e option).

Here's a [nice reference](http://www.selectorweb.com/grep_tutorial.html) with more general info.

Comment: Actually, using `'\$VAR'` will produce a string with a real backslash in it in every shell I'm aware of, including tcsh, which is the default on his Freebsd system. The backslash won't prevent his grep from working but I have to think it was not intended..

Comment: I think that's what we want here--an actual backslash with an actual dollar sign to be passed as a regex

Comment: Ok, if that's really what you meant. I removed the downvote. (Had to edit your answer to do it.) But remember that `$` is not magic to grep except at the end of the pattern.

Comment: @DigitalRoss- I think in this case you want `grep` to see the backslash. Otherwise `$` might gets interpreted as a metacharacter instead of a character in the text of the file.

Comment: It's only magic at the end of a pattern...anyway it seems clear to me that the OP just wanted to prevent shell variable expansion...